# Serial port vs USB serial adapter timing issues

Tags: usb, serial

I'm working on some code that communicates via RS-485/MODBUS RTU with some devices. Depending on my development needs, sometimes I use a USB-RS485 adapter, other times I use an RS-485 HAT that's connected to serial0.

With the HAT, I get much more frequent timeouts. Looking at the bus with an oscilloscope, the major difference seems to be that the inter-frame time between when a frame was received by the Pi, and when the next frame is sent is very small, smaller than the MODBUS spec calls for (at 19,200 baud, it should be about 2 ms). When using the USB adapter, the inter-frame time is never less than 2 ms.

I’m speculating that this lack of bus quiet time is preventing the device from noticing the new frame, and thus it fails to respond.

Is it possible the USB stack is introducing this delay (it’s an FTDI chip)? I’m not sure how best to solve the problem when using the HAT, other than to introduce a delay before each send in my code. I’ve wrapped `libmodbus` in my own code, and I could go to some lengths to measure the interval since the last frame sent or received, and pad that out to 2 ms, but that’s a lot of work. Introducing the delay would at least help me prove out my theory.

*UPDATE:* Introducing a hard-coded 2 ms delay prior to sending frames seems to have completely solved the issue. This strikes me as a limitation in `libmodbus`; I’ll bring it up with them.

Comment: Good question! +1  The update is appreciated, and please post your answer here when you get it as it may help others. As I read your question, I couldn't help but wonder if the fault lies with your HAT.

Comment: @Seamus The HAT actually works great now that I've added the delay. It has also helped the USB interface work without timeouts. In a response to a bug against libmodbus for a related issue, the author says it "by design" does not respect the MODBUS timing specification. As to why USB is slower, though, I don't know the answer.